# How do I change the default EntityRepository Base Class in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How do I change the default EntityRepository Base Class in Symfony 2?

I have created an extended EntityRepository class in my custom bundle:

```
namespace MyApp\Bundle\ORM;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class MyAppEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{

}
```

How do I change the Symfony config so that it uses MyAppEntityRepository as the base EntityRepository class for all my entities?

Comment: with the generator command?

Comment: No in the configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at the [reference documentation for the Symfony Doctrine Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) you'll spot there's a `default_repository_class` option. So in your `config.yml` file:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                default_repository_class: MyApp\Bundle\ORM\MyAppEntityRepository
```

This is a bit of a change from the default `config.yml` setup for Doctrine so you'd have to move the `auto_mapping` and `naming_strategy` options into there as well - I've included these above for reference, the main answer to your question is the `default_repository_class` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom repository class in the Entity class annotation, e.g.:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    //...
}
```

Doctrine's [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) provides more information on this.

Comment: I wanted it to be global across all Entities without explicit setup on each of the Entity Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Doctrine\ORM\Configuration` class **[on line 706](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php#L706)** is a method `getDefaultRepositoryClassName()`. As you can see in the method it uses a named key `defaultRepositoryClassName` from the configuration. So you can set your custom repository in the doctrine config using this key:

**In Zend Framework 2:**

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'configuration' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'default_repository_class' => 'My\Custom\DefaultRepository'
        )
    )
)
```

**In Symfony**:

`default_repository_class` key in your `config.yml` file

---

Or you can get a `Configuration` instance and use the `setDefaultRepositoryClassName` method **[from line 688](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php#L688)** as also is shown [here in the documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#default-repository-optional):

```
$config->setDefaultRepositoryClassName($defaultRepository);
```